# Docker Add command doesn't work in nested destination directory

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build a simple image that includes a file (jdbc driver for Teamcity) in the image that I will then upload.  When I set the destination to /data/ or /data/teamcity_server/ it works but, if I include the full path of where the file needs to be, it doesn't.  I'm stumped.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jetbrains/teamcity-server
ADD  https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.4.1212.jar /data/teamcity_server/datadir/lib/jdbc/
```

I tried the copy command using a file on disk in the context of the folder i'm building from with the same result.  Surely it's something simple I've missed, but i'm about frustrated at this point.

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
FROM jetbrains/teamcity-server
RUN cd /data/teamcity_server/datadir/lib/jdbc/ \
   && wget https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.4.1212.jar
```

Comment: This doesn't work, presumably because the directory structure doesn't exist.  This could possibly be root cause with copy command though I was under the impression that the copy command (or Add for that matter) created directory structure in its absence.